# Blinking question mark folder icon after Ubuntu USB boot

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup

A few days ago, I booted into Ubuntu from a USB drive on my late 2011 13'' MacBook Pro. The computer has an SSD that was installed about 5 years ago to improve performance.

Yesterday, I turned my computer on, it booted normally, I logged in, startup programs opened up, and then it froze. I left it by itself for a while, came back, and it was still frozen. I restarted it and got a blank screen with a blinking question mark in a folder icon.

I first tried rebooting it again, to no avail. I rebooted into recovery mode so that I could use Disk Utility to copy the computer's drive into an external HDD. Disk Utility sees my internal drive, but when choosing Restore I get the following error message:

**restore failed, could not validate source - error 254**

I then tried booting into Ubuntu with the same flash drive, which worked and ran

`sudo fdisk -l`

in the Ubuntu terminal, which again shows (among other things) my internal drive (it appears as /media/newhd). I then ran

`sudo mkdir /media/newhd`
`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newhd`

I again get an error message, this time it reads:

**mount: /media/newhd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error**

Where do I go from here? I could try Clonezilla, but my understanding is that it can be quite painful to use. I've also read the hard drive cable can become damaged with time, so I was considering buying a SATA to USB adapter and trying to access the internal SSD from another computer, so as to determine if the disk itself is still working. Is there anything else I can do?

I don't recall there being anything super important on the computer, but I'd rather try more data recovery options before wiping everything and doing a clean install of some OS (of course, assuming the disk itself is not the problem).

UPDATE:

I finally got a SATA to USB cable and plugged the internal disk into another MacBook Pro. I got the "This disk is unreadable by this computer warning", which seems quite strange? I ran First Aid via Diks Utility to no exciting results. Disk Utility is also saying that the drive has exactly 0 free space.

Does this mean that the drive is dead?

Comment: What OS was it running before the crash? I doubt Ubuntu could read APFS, so would be bound to give error messages.

Comment: @Tetsujin Some version of macOS, I don't remember exactly what. Definitely not Big Sur. I *think* High Sierra, but may have been something newer.

Comment: It *sounds* like a disk error of some sort, just from the symptoms. I would be tempted to try it in an external USB drive caddy. Remember that the drive is likely HFS+ which is unsupported on anything but macOS without additional software on Linux or Windows. But that would help you determine if it is hardware or something fixable with a disk repair utility.

Comment: @SteveChambers Would that be different from using a SATA to USB cable to try accessing the disk? I've never used a USB drive caddy.

Comment: I *think* we are talking about the same thing. An adapter that lets you attach an 'internal' drive externally via USB

Comment: Try restarting your Mac while holding down Command + R with the internet disconnected.

Comment: @slartibartfast is there a way of doing that besides getting into a Faraday cage? Even if I turn off my wifi, the computer will probably try to connect to other local public networks.

Comment: @Reveillark “will probably…” so not tried but assuming hurdles?

Comment: @Reveillark turning your Wifi off will most likely suffice. If you are in a place where you connected to a variety of networks, please go somewhere else. If you’re not on High Sierra but a previous MacOS: trying restarting your Mac while holding down the Option/Alt-key. This brings up a list of icons representing your connected drives/partitions and you can select the one to boot from.

Comment: @slartibartfast Ok, I tried (with both key combinations), but all the computer does is prompt me to choose a network for internet recovery.